# Why $\mathcal A$ is not bounded below?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, order-theory

This is an example of Amann analysis book, what I dont understand clearly:

> Let $X$ be a set with at least two elements and $\mathcal X:=\mathcal P (X)\setminus\{\emptyset\}$ with the inclusion order. Suppose further that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty disjoint subsets of $X$ and $\mathcal A:=\{A,B\}$.
>
> Then $\mathcal A\subseteq\mathcal X$ and $\sup(\mathcal A)=A\cup B$, but $\mathcal A$ has no maximum, and $\mathcal A$ is not bounded below. In particular $\inf(\mathcal A)$ does not exist.

What I cant see is why the empty set is not the infimum of $\mathcal A$, because we have that $\emptyset \subseteq A$ and $\emptyset\subseteq B$, i.e.

$$\emptyset\subseteq x,\forall x\in \mathcal A$$

Then, what is wrong in my interpretation? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By fiat (first sentence of your quote), the empty set $\emptyset$ is assumed to *not* be an element of $\mathcal{X}$, your partial order.

Comment: I though about that but this doesnt mean that the empty set is not a subset of the elements of the power set, not the power set itself. Oh, I think I understand... the empty set is excluded not only of the power set if not the partial order.

Comment: Be careful about your sets. Your set $\mathcal{X}$, being a subset of $P(X)$, is the set you are interested in. The infimum of a subset of $\mathcal{X}$ is **an element of $\mathcal{X}$**, not a subset thereof.

Comment: Oh, ok, I understand... a relation is defined in some set. In this case the set doesnt contain the empty set.

Comment: That's exactly the case. This is basically a manufactured case where you take a poset $\mathcal{Y}$ and elements $A,B$ in $\mathcal{Y}$, and artificially remove _all lower bounds_ (there's only one of them in your example) of $\{A,B\}$ from $\mathcal{Y}$, and call the resulting poset $\mathcal{X}$.

Answer (score 2):

The empty set would serve as the infimum of $\mathcal{A}$, and the union $A \cup B$ serves as an upper bound of both $A$ and $B$.  But since $A \nleq B$ and $B \nleq A$, no maximum exists *in* $\mathcal{A}$ (though it can be found in $\mathcal{X}$).  And since $\emptyset \not\in \mathcal{X}$, the infimum cannot be found in $\mathcal{X}$ at all.

Remember that $\mathcal{X}$ is not an algebra, so it isn't bound to be closed under complements, etc., and that's partially the point of the example.